# Is cascading I/O streams a bad practice?

Tags: java

Does the following code result in a resource leakage?

```
JarOutputStream jo = null;
    try
    {
        File f = new File("myinput.txt");
        jo = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            if(jo!=null)
                jo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

If the creation of `JarOutputStream` fails, does this cause any resource leakage as the `FileOutputStream` is already built?

Answer (score 2):

Hypothetically, yes it would leak resources if the `JarOutputStream` constructor threw an exception.  (Certainly, the javadoc is not clear on this point.)

However, with this particular usage, it is hard to see how the constructor *could* throw an exception.  And examination of the source code (Java 6 through Java 8) suggests that the only exceptions that could happen here would be subclasses of `Error` ... which you should not attempt to recover from.

---

So is it bad practice?

It really depends on the context.

- If the application is going to attempt to recover from an exception in `JarOutputStream` and do the same sort of thing repeatedly, then you could get into serious problems because of the resource leakage.
- If not, well ... it doesn't matter that much.

---

The other question is what is the best way to code this.  My preference would be to write it like this:

```
File f = new File("myinput.txt");
try (FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
     JarOutputStream jo = new JarOutputStream(fo)) {
    // write stuff to jo
} catch(IOException ex) {
    // diagnose errors
}
```

However, the code above is "confining" the `JarOutputStream` to the try block.  If you really need to use the stream object outside of the block (e.g. because you are returning it) then try-with-resources doesn't help.  You will need to code it close the `FileOutputStream` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may have a leakage because when constructor of JarOutputStream is called, the stream object is linked to your file

```
JarOutputStream jo = null;
FileOutputStream myOut = null;
    try
    {
        myOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("myinput.txt"));
        jo = new JarOutputStream(myOut);
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            if(jo!=null)
                jo.close();
            if(myOut!=null)
                myOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely it's a bad practice, for it can cause leakage.

As a general rule, each *closeable* resource should be open into a try-with-resources statement. Furthermore, it makes the code more readable:

```
try (OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(file))
{
    try (JarOutputStream jo=new JarOutputStream(out))
    {
        ...
    }
    // optional catches...
}
// optional catches...
```

Also, remember that a `catch` clause should not be empty (it might hide execution errors).

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question:

```
jo = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
```

equals

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
jo = new JarOutputStream(fos); //if this throws exception, fos is never closed
```

To deal with this problem, you could either:

**Wrap a try block into another**, which would probably be very ugly. If you are stuck to a Java version where the next idea is not available, I would suggest not to rewrite your code to be "totally" safe, unless it is really necessary (you open a vast amount of resources all the time and your program is running so long it would really matter if they are not closed)

Or you could **use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)**, which is available since Java 7:

```
File f = new File ("foo");
try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream (f);
    JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream (fos)) {
  //do sth
} catch (IOException e) {
  //log exception, etc.
}
```

This would make both streams automatically closed after your code is executed, and in addition it is much nicer than handcrafted finally-code.